# Is there a 'set paste' option in Emacs to paste paste from external clipboard?

Tags: vim, emacs, terminal, copy-paste, putty

I am using Emacs on a remote machine which has no X-window through putty. The problem is that the copy/paste from external clipboard(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>) is quite slow.

In Vim, there is an option `set paste` when I need to paste, then is there any similar function for Emacs?

I am currently trying some workarounds: before pasting, I change the major-mode into `fundamental-mode`, then I disable the minor modes displayed in modeline to make the side effect as minimal as possible. However it is still much slower than when started with `emacs -Q`.
And in the display area(minibuffer), there are messages starting with *"matches ... "*(parentheses, etc.).

So how to solve it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of such a "paste mode" for Emacs.  You could start with something like the following (new version, using a separate buffer, so that the current buffer's *-change-functions only get called once at the end):

```
(defvar ttypaste-mode nil)
(add-to-list 'minor-mode-alist '(ttypaste-mode " Paste"))

(defun ttypaste-mode ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (current-buffer))
        (ttypaste-mode t))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (let ((stay t)
            (text (current-buffer)))
        (redisplay)
        (while stay
          (let ((char (let ((inhibit-redisplay t)) (read-event nil t 0.1))))
            (unless char
              (with-current-buffer buf (insert-buffer-substring text))
              (erase-buffer)
              (redisplay)
              (setq char (read-event nil t)))
            (cond
             ((not (characterp char)) (setq stay nil))
             ((eq char ?\r) (insert ?\n))
             ((eq char ?\e)
              (if (sit-for 0.1 'nodisp) (setq stay nil) (insert ?\e)))
             (t (insert char)))))
        (insert-buffer-substring text)))))
```

Comment: It's really much faster! Would you please explain a bit about this snippet? Seems that there is still space to improve it:-)

Comment: I updated the code with a slightly faster version (in a c-mode buffer, the difference is very significant).  I haven't been able to speed this up any further tho (30s for 900KB on an AMD-E350).  Maybe skipping the `(eq char ?\r)` test and doing a `subst-char-in-region` at the end would help, but I doubt the difference will be large.

Comment: Thanks so much, works fine; and I'll try to understand the code.

Comment: BTW, in recent Emacsen, a similar piece of code is used automatically (at least in those text-terminals which support the "bracketed paste" feature), so you shouldn't need any of that gymnastics any more.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer something a bit more tested and used:

```
;; enable clipboard interaction between emacs and system
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
```

It works for me. A simple C-y and you are good to go!
Hope that helps.

Comment: No, I do not. Sorry I oversaw that detail. Did you try using C-S-v to use your Terminal clipboard? I tried that and it works with emacsclient -t on my system. If that is not satisfactory you could try something like xsel to have an external X clipboard manager for terminal usage. If that is still unsatisfactory you could try somthing like [these methods](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/CopyAndPaste#toc6). Please tell if these work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work since I am using __putty__ connecting to a remote machine, which doesn't have X-window server. Also, C-S-v doesn't respond(at least `Shift` is eaten).